# TypeError: set_linha() missing 1 required positional argument: 'uma_lista'

Tags: python

when i run the program the error message indicates that there is a type error in `set_linha`

```
def interceta_triangulo(self, reta):
    # retorna
    # (True, pontoIntercecao, t)
    # ou
    # (False, None, None)

    xa = self.ponto1.x
    ya = self.ponto1.y
    za = self.ponto1.z

    xb = self.ponto2.x
    yb = self.ponto2.y
    zb = self.ponto2.z

    xc = self.ponto3.x
    yc = self.ponto3.y
    zc = self.ponto3.z

    xe = reta.origem.x
    ye = reta.origem.y
    ze = reta.origem.z

    xd = reta.vetor_diretor.x ## Aqui a tua direcao e o vector_director? Sim
    yd = reta.vetor_diretor.y
    zd = reta.vetor_diretor.z

    # denominador da regra de Cramer

    A = Matriz(3, 3)
    A.set_linha([[xa-xb, xa-xc, xd],
                 [ya-yb, ya-yc, yd],
                 [za-zb, za-zc, zd]])   
    detA = A.det_3x3()# determinante do denominador

    if abs(detA) < TOLERANCIA_ZERO: ## TOLERANCIA_ZERO
        return(False, None, None)

    # parâmetro t

    tNum = Matriz(3, 3)
    tNum.set_linha([[xa-xb, xa-xc, xa-xe],
                    [ya-yb, ya-yc, ya-ye],
                    [za-zb, za-zc, za-ze]])
    t = tNum.det_3x3() / detA

    if t < TOLERANCIA_ZERO:
        return(False, None, None)

    # coordenada gama

    gamaNum = Matriz(3, 3)
    gamaNum.set_linhas([[xa-xb, xa-xe, xd],
                        [ya-yb, ya-ye, yd],
                        [za-zb, za-ze, zd]])
    gama = gamaNum.det_3x3() / detA

    if gama < 0.0 or gama > 1.0:
        return(False, None, None)

    # coordenada beta

    betaNum = Matriz(3, 3)
    betaNum.set_linhas([[xa-xe, xa-xc, xd], 
                        [ya-ye, ya-yc, yd],
                        [za-ze, za-zc, zd]])
    beta = betaNum.det_3x3() / detA

    if beta < 0.0 or beta > 1.0: ## eu nao pus menos gama
        return(False, None, None)

    # ponto a = ponto 1, ponto b = ponto 2, ponto c = ponto 3
    #
    # P = a + beta(b-a) + gama(c-a)
    vab = self.ponto2 - self.ponto1
    vac = self.ponto3 - self.ponto1

    pontoIntercecao = (self.ponto1 + vab*beta) + vac*gama

    return(True, pontoIntercecao, t)
```

here i'll put the error mensage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Lauro\Documents\isel\1314\4 semestre\mcg\projeto final\pf corrigidos\plano_xxxxx .py", line 73, in interceta_triangulo
    [za-zb, za-zc, zd]])
TypeError: set_linha() missing 1 required positional argument: 'uma_lista'
```

please help i'm relatively new in python

Comment: where is set_linha defined ? you need to show the code for that - or at last the "def" line for it.

Comment: it is part of another code, i'll try to put it in here

Comment: would be better to add it to your question - as it is the key to your problem. looking at your code, you are passing a single list to your call to set_linha, and I assume that the "set_linha" function is expecting two arguments at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are passing a single list to your call to set_linha :

[[xa-xe, xa-xc, xd], [ya-ye, ya-yc, yd], [za-ze, za-zc, zd]]

is a single list with 3 lists inside it, and from the error message, I assume that the "set_linha" function is expecting three arguments at least - one of which will be self.

Without the definition of set_linha, and since I don't understand what your code is trying to do I can't tell you what you what that 2nd argument should be.

Comment: thanks i already resolved it :)